# Using mySQL array object as int

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

I am just beginning to learn PHP, javascript and mySQL.

I have managed to use PHP to turn mySQL results into json array:

```
var arrayObjects = <?php echo json_encode($results); ?>
```

Now I have a javascript array, which I don't know how to use.

If I view "arrayObjects" in the browser console, it shows the following:

```
[Object]
   0: Object
     ID: "1"
     Theme: "2"
     Item1: "0"
     Item2: "1"
     Item3: "2"
```

I would like to use "Theme" as an int in javascript, but I have no idea how I can get that as an int variable.

Comment: try `parseInt(arrayObjects[0].Theme)` or `+arrayObjects[0].Theme` as a shortcut.

Comment: Do you mean by the sentence **"I have a javascript array, which I don't know how to use"** that you can't iterate through `$results` in javascript or just **"how I can get that as an int variable"** ?

Comment: Phuzi's comment helped me out. The problem, was I didn't know the syntax on how to parse the arrayObjects "Theme" into int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the value out of the array in to its own variable, here is a working example:

```
<?php $results = array( "ID" => 1, "Theme" => 2); ?>
<script>

var arrayObjects = <?php echo json_encode($results); ?>

var Theme = arrayObjects['Theme'];

document.write(Theme);

</script>
```

I think you would need to do:

```
var Theme = arrayObjects[0].Theme;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `arrayObjects[0].Theme`

Comment: Seems to be comment which is already posted [**over here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205349/using-mysql-array-object-as-int#comment50412692_31205349)